# Sizing the Mega Menu to page width and centering it

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I am trying to make a mega menu that will be the width of the #header and also centered to the middle. The max-width of the header is 1024px. However the dropdown menu keeps starting at the edge of the parent li. I managed to hack it with margins, but that's not a permanent solution by any means. I've removed the margins for the sake of this question.

HTML

```
<header>
    <div id="header">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="medium-3 columns">
        <div id="logo">
            <a href="#"><img alt="logo" src="http://dummyimage.com/174x114/828282/0011ff.png"/></a>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="medium-7 columns">
            <ul class="nav clearfix animated">
                <li class="border-half"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li class="border-half">
                    <a href="#">Series</a>
                    <div class="mega-container1">
                        <div style="width: 1000px; height: 290px;"></div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="border-half"><a href="#">Members</a>
                    <div class="mega-container2">
                        <div style="width: 1000px; height: 290px;"></div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="border-half">
                    <a href="#">About</a>
                    <div class="mega-container3">
                        <ul style="width: 1000px; height: 290px;">
                            <li><a href="#">Who We Are</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Why We Care</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Some other page</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">How We Work</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="border-half"><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="medium-2 columns">
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

CSS

```
body {font-size: 16px; background: #cacaca;}
#wrapper{width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 0; margin: 0; background: #cacaca;}
header {width: 100%; max-height: 7.188em; background: #fff; border-bottom: 0.063em solid $header-border; z-index: 1;}
#header{max-width: 1024px; height: 7.125em; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0; background: #cdecde}
#logo {max-width: 10.875em; max-height: 7.125em; float: left; background: #eee;}
* { -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;}
* { -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;}
.nav {
    background: #cdecde;
    max-width: 500px;
    height: 114px;
}

.nav li { list-style: none;  }
.nav > li { padding: 0; float: left; position: relative; }
.nav > li > a {
    float: left;
    color: $body-font-color;
    font-size: $paragraph-font-size;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 114px;
    padding: 0 20px; 
    height: 114px;
    position: relative;
    border-left: 1px solid #fff;
}
.nav > li:hover > a { background: #F7F7F7; border-left: 1px solid #f1f1f1;}
.nav > li:first-child > a {  }
.nav > li:last-child > a { border-right: 0;}
.nav > li:hover > div { display: block; }

/* Mega Dropdown */

.nav > li > div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 114px;
    display: none;
    background: #F7F7F7;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    overflow: hidden;
    border-bottom: 4px solid $primary-color;
    border-left: 1px solid $header-border;
    border-right: 1px solid $header-border;
    z-index: 2;
    max-width: 1024px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.mega-container1 { 
    left: ;
}
.mega-container2 { 
    left: ;
}
.mega-container3 { 
    left: ;
}
.clearfix:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.border-half {
    border-right: 1px solid #F0F0F0;
    position: relative;
}
.border-half:before {
    border-left: 1px solid #cdecde;
}
.border-half:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    height: 50px;
    top: 0px;
    right: -1px;
    border: 1px solid #cdecde;
}
.border-half:hover::after {
    right: -3px;
}
```

Here is a JSFiddle to get the idea: http://jsfiddle.net/7e3esmpx/

Update 1: The explanation was a little confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Alright I think I have a solution to your problem. From my understanding, you want the hidden divs to appear when hovered, and take up the entire screen's width. Is that correct? To do that:

First add the position of fixed and a left margin of 0 to your nav li divs when they are hovered. i.e.:

```
.nav > li:hover > div { display: block;
                        position: fixed;
                        left: 0}
```

Change the max width on your nav li divs to contain the entire screen. i.e.:

```
.nav > li > div {
position: absolute;
top: 114px;
display: none;
background: #F7F7F7;
padding: 10px 10px;
box-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
overflow: hidden;
border-bottom: 4px solid $primary-color;
border-left: 1px solid $header-border;
border-right: 1px solid $header-border;
z-index: 2;
max-width: 1800px;
height: auto;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: I am sorry If I didn't explain it very well. What I want is the hidden div to be the width of the #header so if the #header is 1024px the max width of the hidden div should be 1024px and also the hidden div should be in the middle of the screen.

Comment: I am looking into a way to do this. Not that easy (for me at least lol)

I would probably look into hardcoding the hidden div in it's permanent location, then using javascript to pull in the dynamic content for each li on hover. Would you entertain the idea of using javascript, or do you want to stick to html and css?

Comment: I'm glad I'm not the only one to be baffled with this. Well... This navigation has to magically size down for mobile as well. So I prefer CSS/HTML but if there's no option I guess I could do JS... I did manage to lock it in place but go bellow a certain window size and it's back to the drawing board.

Comment: Maybe try that approach with media queries?

Comment: I think I may be onto something. Will post an answer if I solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the UL had a certain width. And the dropdown was the same size of the UL meaning that if I resize the UL I should get the same width. So anyone having a similar issue, check your UL.